# Adding Ability To Change Only Given Category In This Code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently had this code created for my Wordpress site.  It makes it so that unregistered users can not see the newest posts available up to 15 days unless they register.  It works, but I need it to only restrict one specific category in my Wordpress installation and not all of them (i.e. I need it to restrict this category but not my blog posts).

Can anyone tell me where and what is needed to make this code function this way?  Thanks.

```
    add_filter('posts_where', '_custom_s2member_archive_filter');
function _custom_s2member_archive_filter($where) /* Require membership to view latest content. */
    {
        if(!is_admin() && (is_archive() || is_home()) && !current_user_can("access_s2member_level1"))
            {
                $where .= " AND post_date <= '".date ("Y-m-d", strtotime ("-15 days"))."'"; /* Back-date freeloaders. */
            }
        return $where;
    }
add_filter('template_redirect', '_custom_s2member_single_filter');
function _custom_s2member_single_filter() /* Require membership to view latest content. */
    {
        global $post; /* Need this for date comparison. */
        if(!is_admin() && is_single() && !current_user_can("access_s2member_level1"))
            {
                if(strtotime($post->post_date) > strtotime("-15 days"))
                    {
                        header("Location: ".S2MEMBER_MEMBERSHIP_OPTIONS_PAGE_URL);
                        exit();
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: The person who wrote the code for you won't change it? :)

Comment: So you want to restrict one category, but keep other posts unrestricted? The easiest way to do this would be to filter after you query, but this would give strange archives (not always the same number of posts per page). Is it ok if they see "There is a post here, but you can't see it until you register" in the archives?

Comment: A little more background:  This is all being run through a theme called Comicpress (comicpress.org).  Basically I want the comic category to be filtered but not the blog posts.  I hope that maybe makes things a little clearer. :)

@songdogtech I seem to be having trouble motivating the person who wrote the code to fix this part since I foolishly paid them already.

Comment: The way it's set up now, if the person tries to click on a link to one of the comics out of their window of "viewable comics", they are automatically forwarded to the sign up page by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Start by figuring out what the ID of the category in question is. You can get that by going to Posts -> Categories in the Admin sidebar, then click on the category you're trying to restrict. The URL for the new page you are lead to will end in tag_ID=[some number]. That [some number] is the category ID.

Then use Wordpress's [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) to write an if statement like 

`if(is_category('[some number]')) 

{ 

Put the code you already have for restricting the posts here 

}`

Granted, I have not tested this myself, but let me know how it works out!